# Code issues in holoViewer for MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have been working on the same computer and after the 1st of the year my directory of the hard drive that I have been saving my work changed from a `H:` drive to a `G:` drive.
Now the function `holoViewer` will not work.
The code gives me this error; How do I fix this?

> Undefined function or variable 'img'.
>
> Error in holoViewer>holoViewer_OpeningFcn (line 147)
>   handles.originalImage = img();
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 220)
>      feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});
>
> Error in holoViewer (line 133)
>      gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Comment: Can't you change the Unit name back to H?

Comment: Have you checked your `path`?  What is `img()` and where have you defined it?